# MSVC compiler update

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2012

Can I update MSVC2010 compilter to MSVC2012 but still with the MSVC2010 integrated development environment? If I have some third party like QT which is compiled with MSVC2010, can I still use it after the updating? Thanks

Comment: "If I have some third party like QT which is compiled with MSVC2010, can I still use it after the updating?" I don't know definitively for these two but in general it's not safe to change major versions for C++ compilers because of ABI changes, name mangling changes or STL header changes.

Comment: You can use MSVC2012 IDE with 2010 platform toolset.

Comment: I am too interested in using the VS 2012 compiler with the VS2010 IDE. Although for the OP even if that was possible it will not make libraries from VS2010 work with the 2012 compiler. Qt (at least version 4.8 and lower) itself is easy to compile for VS2012 so that should not hold you back.

Answer (score 0):

For the x86 build environment, write this in a batch file. Remove the call keyword if commands are typed in the command line:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /useenv
```

Take a look at other shortcuts in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools too see how to setup for x64 or ARM builds.

Intellisense probably should be turned off as the old engine complains a lot about new language constructs (e.g. range-based for statement). Debugger gets correct reading on a vector despite the size change in VC11 but I am not sure how much trust you want to put on the visualizers for other types.